# How to find a word in a string?

Tags: javascript

The challenge is to "find Waldo." I'm trying to figure out how to find a word in a function/string." Return the index of where in the string 'Waldo' starts."

```
function findWaldo(str) {
    var waldoPosition;
    return waldoPosition
}
```

Comment: Have you tried searching at all? It's a concept many languages implement, called `indexOf` and returns the index of a certain string or element in an iterable.

Comment: Perhaps you should try googling it first.

Answer (score 0):

Simple task to do:

```
function findWaldo(str) {
    return str.indexOf("waldo"); //the string you are looking for
}
```

It is explained quite well [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

Answer (score 0):

There should be a library that does it easily, like `string.indexOf`, but you can do it manually with this algorithm:

```
int count = 0;
string yourText = "This is waldo?";
string toSearch = "waldo";

for (int x = 0; x < yourText.Lenght; x++)
{
    if(yourText[x] == toSearch[0])
        if((count + 1) == toSearch.Lenght)
            return x;
    else
        count = 0;

   //here we'd say ehh there's not Waldo on the string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a word or letter you can use x.indexOf method, hope to below code helps.

```js
// Question
const findWord = (str, findWord) =>{
    let total = ""
    let error = false
    let errorMessage = "";
    if(str != null && str != ""){
        error = false
        if(!str.indexOf(findWord)){
            total = `there is no ${findWord} in str peremeter.
            `
        }else{
            total = `the position of ${findWord} is ${str.indexOf(findWord)}`
        }
    }else{
        error = true;
        errorMessage = "Please fill the str perimeter."
        return errorMessage
    }
    return total
}

// Calling Function
console.log(findWord("Hello World", "World"))
```